# "Could not cast value of type" when try to pushViewController

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have two classes `MenuVC`, `CategoryVC` and `CategorySubclassVC` (which is a subclass of `CategoryVC` and I used it to fill data). I also have a Storyboard for `CategoryVC` with Storyboard ID `categoryID`.

In `didSelectRowAt indexPath` I tried to push view controller from `MenuVC` to `CategorySubclassVC`:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "categoryID") as! CategorySubclassVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

I get an error: Could not cast value of type 'My_App.CategoryVC' to 'My_App.CategorySubclassVC'.

Is it possible to push view controller in this way? If I change the destination to CategoryVC all works fine. The problem appears for Subclass (CategorySubclassVC).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me.

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "categoryID") as! CategoryVC
object_setClass(secondViewController, CategorySubclassVC)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```